# Loop foreach and while but how use in C# Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, foreach, while-loop

Do you know how i could use the loop "while" and "foreach" to display the results
For my code :

Control.cs :

```
IEnumerable<Acces> all_id = acces_Repository.FindAll("where email = '" + id_ + "'");
ViewBag.Acceslist = all_id;
ViewBag.Liste = listeRepository.FindAll(" order by id ASC ");
```

Function.cs :

```
public IEnumerable<Acces> FindAll(string where = "")
        {
            try { 
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                return dbConnection.Query<Acces>("SELECT * FROM access "+where);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ex.ToString();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I would like for its result in acces.cshtml:

```
<select class=" chosen-select form-control form-control-sm" name="id" value="" multiple="multiple">
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Liste)
 {
    @foreach (var item12 in ViewBag.Acces_liste)
    {
       @if (item.Id == item12.Id)
       {
          <option value="@item12.Id" checked selected="selected">@item12.Id</option>
       } else {
          <option value="@item.Id">@item.Id</option>
       }
     }
 }
 </select>
```

I have two functions which do not return the same results but come from the same database. In order to display all the results but selecting the correct ones.
To get this result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdbKI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forms inside foreach loop in Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157469/forms-inside-foreach-loop-in-razor-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC Razor, add if statement to foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301821/mvc-razor-add-if-statement-to-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's try to go over on how you can display your result set on your `View`.

You can either use `ViewBag` to assign your list and then iterate over it on your View

OR

You can use a strongly typed model binding on your View. I prefer to use this method as it gives your a more concrete implementation.

Regarding your case, you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<Acces> all_id = acces_Repository.FindAll("where email = '" + id_ + "'");
ViewBag.Acceslist = all_id;
```

And you can simply loop over this list on your `View` like this:

```
<ul>
    @if(ViewBag.Acceslist !=null)
    {
      @foreach(var data ViewBag.Acceslist)
      {
        <li>@data.Id</li>        
      }
    }
</ul>
```

You would need to check for `null` otherwise your `View` would crash if a null value is encountered.

You can use `LINQ` methods to do a join our lists and get your required data in one single list which you can send to your `View`. You can do something like:

```
IEnumerable<Acces> all_id = acces_Repository.FindAll("where email = '" + id_ + "'");
var liste = listeRepository.FindAll(" order by id ASC ");

var all_id_list=all_id.ToList();
var liste_list=liste.ToList();

var myList= from a in all_id_list
           join l in liste_list on a.Id equals l.Id
           where a.EmailId == "myemail@example.com"

ViewBag.displayMyList=myList;
```

And then you can loop over this ViewBag on your `View` to show the result.

Comment: Yes thanks work with your code, but I take this opportunity to go further. I modified, for my final result

Comment: I've used this before but I haven't been able to compare the two results

Comment: I would like to compare two results (like acces.cshtml) and be able to select the ones that need to be

Comment: I edited, I don't know if you see i research

Comment: yes select or deselect and to have rights on one of the selected choices

Comment: Precisely my 2 requests on several results ... I do not see how to do otherwise...

Comment: No, but I think I should display the results I want to select in one query, then another with the rest. But it's not the same table .. so I'm looking

Comment: yes I have 3 tables. First : table1.column1 = table2.column.1 and table1.coloumn2 = table3.column 1

Comment: I want the results of column 2 which correspond to an email address of column 1

Comment: Okay I understand, would you have a little example?

Comment: @Toomy I have updated my answer with a small example on how you can join two lists based on a condition and I have tried to keep it as close to your scenario as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
 int temp = 0;

 foreach (Acces item in all_id)
 {
    ViewBag.liste[temp] = item.Id;
    temp ++;
 }
```

Or you can simply do this:

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < all_id.Count(); temp++)
{
  ViewBag.liste[temp] = all_id[temp].Id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can Use Why Not
but i think you if Use this code  then it is better

```
for  (int i=0;i < all_id.Count();i++)
{
     foreach (Acces item in all_id)
     {
        ViewBag.liste[i] = item.Id;
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but i have this error : 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'

Comment: you must send full code can we found where is your problem

Comment: Every item in Viewbag will have the last item from all_id...

Comment: I have edit my post. I would like to recover all the results :)

Comment: @Toomy please make sure you check your Viewbag as that seems to be null

Comment: @Jawad yes it is null before my loop "while"

Comment: If your viewbag is null, you need to initialize it before assigning values to its elements